# Unable to update / Upgrade / install software

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

Thank you for taking the time to take a look at this,  I have dug through other forums relating to this issue but can't seem to pinpoint the problem.  I am fairly new to ubuntu command line as well - so i will do my best to keep up.

general info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$  uname -a
Linux danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The process:

```
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
80 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/155 MB of archives.
After this operation, 11.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
**E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)**
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$
```

I had to cut out a bunch of the code as i need "at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links" here. Any help would be appreciated.
I also get this error when attempting to install anything from the from Software center:

```
Package operation failed
The installation or removal of a software package failed.
installArchives() failed: 
Extracting templates from packages: 75%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%

Extracting templates from packages: 75%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%

Extracting templates from packages: 75%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Error in function:
```

Comment: Was there a package error before the `**E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)**` error?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have ubuntu's UI installation software open the (software center), while you're running this command at terminal?

Comment: No sir, there were no package errors, I checked thoroughly.  Also, And the software center was on a different login session.  not simultaneously.

Comment: After running another apt-get update'  I came across this error:

Comment: disregard that last comment, it was just a connection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suspect disk problems:

First check available diskspace:

```
df -h
```

No lines with 100% should be there in the column Use%

Second, check wether any of you regular filesystems are not mount read-only:

```
mount | egrep '^\/'
```

If there is an 'ro' between the () instead of 'rw', solve that first.

Comment: Here are my results on your suggestions:

danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       348G  4.0G  327G   2% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.9G  4.0K  2.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           592M  1.2M  591M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.9G  148K  2.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ mount | egrep '^\/'
/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: I believe I am seeing an (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Comment: No, it is mounted rw (read-write), the errors=remount-ro is what would happen in case of errors. To be even more sure of the disk/filesystem being ok,  reboot and repeat the above commands, which should give the same results. You left out the interesting part of "anything from the from Software center:" namely what is after the "Error in function:". Are you sure you cant scroll any further in the diaglog box of the message?

Comment: My asumption would now be some package fails to upgrade. I would run "sudo apt-get clean", clearing the local cache of downloaded packages, run "sudo apt update" and then run "sudo apt --download-only upgrade", which would reveal the package names and download them the same time. Next goto the cache "cd /var/cache/apt/archives" and manually upgrade the downloaded packages one by one by running "sudo dpkg -i <filename>". That would show at least which packge is the problem.

Comment: As far as the software center error; there is nothing to scroll down upon other than what i listed as a result.

Comment: When running sudo apt update:  
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Ran:
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update 
result:
Fetched 31.8 MB in 23s (1,354 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: sudo apt --download-only upgrade
Fetched 221 MB in 1min 34s (2,350 kB/s)                                        
Download complete and in download only mode.

Comment: Initializing download of first package within "cd /var/cache/apt/archives";
User-space parser utility for AppArmor.  selecting upgrade.  Result: Package operation failed. (The installation or removal of a software package failed.) details: installArchives() failed: Error in function:

Comment: It feels like hard drive failure, but i just installed ubuntu... this is a 1.3mb file.  I just dont understand.

Comment: You are doing the right thing. Dont know what you mean by "User-space parser utility for AppArmor. selecting upgrade...". Try it with the "dpkg -i filename" method I mentioned from a terminal window. The error message will then be in the clear. Drive failure is as good as ruled out by your actions till now, a hardware error like that would have had far more impact. The thing that has me worried now is the AppArmor thingy....

Comment: danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ dpkg -i filename
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
danger@danger-Samsung-DeskTop-System:~$ sudo -i dpkg -i filename
[sudo] password for danger: 
dpkg: error: reading package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available': Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

JDeHaan,

Thank you kindly through your patient support throughout all of this,  I got frustrated last night at 2am after a couple cocktails and decided to just reinstall.  After many attempts at formatting, repartitioning, and getting write errors during the installation process It's beginning to look like it was an HD failure issue.  One attempt finally made it through and I am able to install and update software now.

Thanks again!